# How many elements of order $p^7$ are in $C_{p^5}\times C_{p^6}\times C_{p^7} \times C_{p^8}\times C_{p^9}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Consider the group $G=C_{p^5}\times C_{p^6}\times C_{p^7}\times C_{p^8}\times C_{p^9}$.
>
> 1) How many elements in $C_{p^k}$ have order at most $p^i$ for $i\leq k$?
>
> 2) How many elements of order $p^7$ are in $G$?

**My ideas:** For part 1), the number of elements of order at most $p^i$ is
$$
\eta(p^i)=\sum_{d\mid p^i}\varphi(d)=\varphi(1)+\varphi(p)+\ldots+\varphi(p^{i-1})+\varphi(p^i).
$$
For part 2), I am thinking to argue as follows. Any element $x=(r,s,t,u,v)\in G$ must satisfy $\text{ord}(x)=\text{lcm}(\text{ord}(r),\ldots,\text{ord}(v))$. We need $\text{ord}(x)=p^7$, so we can pick any elements $r\in C_{p^5}$, $s\in C_{p^6}$, and $t\in C_{p^7}$, and then an element of order $p^7$ from either $C_{p^8}$ or $C_{p^9}$, and finally an element of order at most $p^7$ from whichever of $C_{p^8}$ or $C_{p^9}$ we did not pick the element of order $p^7$. To be more specific, we have $$p^5p^6p^7\varphi(p^7)\eta(p^7)+p^5p^6p^7\eta(p^7)\varphi(p^7)=2p^{18}(p^6(p-1))\eta(p^7)$$ elements of order $p^7$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function, and $\eta$ is the function given in my solution to part 1). My questions are, first of all, is this even correct? Second of all, is there a way to simplify this?

EDIT: Isn't $\eta(p^i)=p^i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements of order $\le p^7$ is $p^5 p^6 p^7 p^7 p^7$ and the number of elements of order $\le p^6$ is $p^5 p^6 p^6 p^6 p^6$.

Comment: This makes sense. I see now that I overcounted a bit in my original solution.

Comment: Just how I would have argued/